# gulp-typescript giving module not found error for angular2

Tags: gulp, angular

I use gulp-typescript to compile the angular2 app. I get the following error.

> C:/src/Terminal.Web/src/Terminal.Web/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(3,53):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx'.
>   C:/src/Terminal.Web/src/Terminal.Web/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(4,25):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx'.
>   [12:18:32] TypeScript: 4 semantic errors
>   C:/src/Terminal.Web/src/Terminal.Web/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/async.d.ts(5,22):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Operator'.
>   C:/src/Terminal.Web/src/Terminal.Web/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(2,22):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BrowserNodeGlobal'.

This is the gulp task.

```
paths.appJs = "app/**/*.ts";
paths.appNg2ComponentsJs = "ng2components/**/*.ts";
paths.appHtml = "app/**/*.html";
paths.appJsOut = paths.webroot + "app/";
paths.angualr2Typings = "node_modules/angular2/typings/";

gulp.task("compile-app-components", function () {

    var tscResult = gulp.src([paths.appNg2ComponentsJs, paths.angualr2Typings + "**/*.d.ts"])
        .pipe(tsc({
            "target": "es5",
            "module": "system",
            "declaration": false,
            "noImplicitAny": false,
            "removeComments": true,
            "noLib": false,
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "listFiles": true,
        }));

    return tscResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.appJsOut));
});
```

Comment: You don't need to feed gulp-typescript with .d.ts, it will find it automatically from angular 2. Start with that.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not add `.d.ts` definition files to your gulp build task:

```
paths.appJs = "app/**/*.ts";
paths.appNg2ComponentsJs = "ng2components/**/*.ts";
paths.appHtml = "app/**/*.html";
paths.appJsOut = paths.webroot + "app/";

gulp.task("compile-app-components", function () {    
    var tscResult = gulp.src([paths.appNg2ComponentsJs, paths.appJs])
        .pipe(tsc({
            "target": "es5",
            "module": "system",
            "declaration": false,
            "noImplicitAny": false,
            "removeComments": true,
            "noLib": false,
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "listFiles": true
        }));

    return tscResult.js
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.appJsOut));
});
```

Moreover, you need to write

```
///<reference path="path/to/file.d.ts" />
```

lines at the beginning of your `.ts` scripts (i.e. to those in `paths.appJs`) where they are necessary (TypeScript compiler tells you when it does not know an identifier).

Comment: I this a bug? In TypeScript 1.7.5, using `tsc` via the command line and without the reference tag, I get no such `Cannot find module` errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSPM the solution is move the tsconfig to wwwroot

Add the following line to the  wwwroot/tsconfig.json  so that systemjs won’t try to load sourcemaps:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "jspm_packages"
  ]
}
```